# Bootstrap how to create right column on form group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `bootstrap` form like the one below.

I want to make the `width` of that column to be 9 so in the left 3 I can add a button to the top-right of the `textarea`.

[image]

The form HTML is:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Compose Message</label>
                <textarea  class="form-control" rows="5" value="" />

            </div>
```

[image]

I have tried using `<div class="col-md-9">` and `<div class="col-md-3">` but no success.

> Any clue?

Comment: Try to place your columns in col-md-12 and whole thing in class "row"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Compose Message</label>
         <textarea  class="form-control" rows="5" value="" />
       </div>      
   </div> 
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn">Button</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just amazing :)